# Ruby method_missing usage in class and module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How `method_missing` can be used both in class and mixed module?

```
module Bar
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    p 'Bar' if name =~ /bar/
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    p 'Foo' if name =~ /foo/
  end
end

a = Foo.new
a.foofoo => "Foo"
a.barbar => nil
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `super`:

```
module Bar
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    p 'Bar' if name =~ /bar/
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    p 'Foo' if name =~ /foo/
    super # ⇐ HERE
  end
end

a = Foo.new
a.foofoo => "Foo"
a.barbar => "Bar"
```

---

As pointed out by @ndn in comments, one might carefully handle different outcomes. `super` might be tuned to be used if and only if the `Foo#method_missing` implementation did not succeed:

```
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    case name
    when /foo/ then p 'Foo'
    # .....
    else super # ⇐ HERE
    end
  end
```

Comment: @ndn indeed, but constructing a robust `case-when` inside `method_missing` is kinda out of scope of this question.

Comment: @ndn yes, I finally decided to drop a notice about into the answer. Thanks.